# Reading (GET) and Editing (PUT) in one place through API (JSON)

Tags: open-source, api, json

I really wanted you to give you a better post-title, but I really don't know how to describe my question in other words.

What I'm looking for (and thought it would be a short search), seems to be hard to find.
To make it easier to manage data from our webshop, I'm looking for a piece of software / self-hosted solution to:

- Read data
- Change / Update data
- Delete data
- Sort data
- Filter data

by connecting to the database through API (JSON)

I don't know where to look.. It would be great if there's a free / open-source solution

Thank you very much in advance!

[EDIT] I'm actually looking for a Ready to Use software without the need of development skills. Like Postman, but more practical.

We're using Lightspeed HQ as shop-environment which doesn't give direct database access, but it has an API to be used with the right credentials. There's also a Postman library available.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! It might help to mention what webshop you use, or at least how the data is stored. Data could be anything from a collection of files to some relational database – so without those details it's not clear what such API should build upon.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you start taking a look at the use of [python](https://www.python.org/) to interact with databases via JSON APIs there is a nice walk through [here](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/python-api-tutorial/) that makes use of the installable [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) library (`pip install requests`) and the [JSON](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html?highlight=json#module-json) library *(built in to the standard library)*.

Certainly you should probably also look at [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) for converting your API responses into data frames for easy filtering, sorting, etc. this can be as simple as:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('http//your-query-url')

j = r.json()

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(j)
```

All of the above software is:

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Cross platform
- Permissive licences